# ORA-38804: not a legal edition name

Tags: oracle11g

While trying to debug the procedure, I am getting the below error at

```
DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RUN_TASK('myTable', l_sql_stmt, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,10);
```

Error:

```
Source breakpoint occurred at line 138 of PROC_MY_PROCEDURE.pls.
Exception breakpoint occurred at line -1 of DBMS_SYS_SQL.pls.
$Oracle.EXCEPTION_ORA_38804: 

ORA-38804: not a legal edition name
```

I have searched on this and it seems the follwing as a cause,

> This error occurred because an attempt was made to create an edition called
>   ORA$BASE, DATABASE_DEFAULT, or USER_DEFAULT. These are not legal
>   edition names. Or a value provided as an edition name is not
>   understandable as an identifier, or is too long.

But in my case how can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working,

We need to use

```
DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RUN_TASK('myTable', l_sql_stmt, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,parallel_level => 10);
```

instead of

```
DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RUN_TASK('myTable', l_sql_stmt, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,10);
```

And we will have to grant `CREATE JOB or CREATE ANY JOB` privilege to the user.